# Java static method seems to be set to instance of a type? (syntax)

Tags: java, syntax

After doing some research on `Comparable`s and `Comparator`s I ran across some funny syntax that looks useful (and that I don't understand).

Example:

```
public static Comparator<Type> TypeComparer = new Comparator<Type>() {
 public int compare(Type a, Type b) {
  return a.compareTo(b);
 }
}
```

I'd really like to know what is going on here. I would never think to use the `=` operator when defining a method. It is a method right? Or a variable containing a method perhaps?

How would I use this object? What should I expect to be returned if I can call it?

If you'd like to look at the original example see [Blog Post](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Comment: It is an anonymous class. It may be nicer with Java 8 Comparators

Comment: now I know what to google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TypeComparer` is not a static method, it's a static field.

Let's walk through the syntax part-by-part:

- `public static Comparator<Type> TypeComparer = ...` declares a field. Its name is `TypeComparer`, and type is `Comparator<Type>`. Since `Comparator<T>` is an interface, the field accepts instances of any class implementing the interface.
- `new Comparator<Type>() { ... }` This syntax defines a new class and creates its instance at the same time. The newly defined class has no name (it's called an anonymous inner class) and its only instance is assigned to `TypeComparer`
- `public int compare(Type a, Type b) { ... }` This is a method of the anonymous comparator class. It implements the method from the `Comparator<T>`, which is required to complete the class.

Users of your class can use the instance of `Comparator<Type>` without knowing its exact type, because they can program to its interface (i.e. call its `compare(...)` method).

**Note:** Starting with Java 8 you can shorten the above example to a single line:

```
public static Comparator<Type> TypeComparer = (a, b) -> {return a.compareTo(b);};
```

Answer (score 3):

> How would I use this object? What should I expect to be returned if I
>   can call it?

You use anonymous class as you don't need to create a named class.
They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time.

It makes sense **only** if you want to define an implementation that is used only in the frame of the class that declares it.
Otherwise, creating a named class is more relevant as it allows to make the class more easily/naturally usable by client classes.

With a named class (`public` or whatever access modifier) you write :

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Type>  {
  public int compare(Type a, Type b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
  }
}
```

And then you can use it :

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator();
```

With anonymous class you write :

```
Comparator<Type> typeComparer = new Comparator<Type>() {
  public int compare(Type a, Type b) {
     return a.compareTo(b);
   }
};
```

and use the variable as any variable :

```
Collections.sort(myList, typeComparer);
```

You could even shorten it by eliminating the `variable`  :

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Type>() {
                            public int compare(Type a, Type b) {
                               return a.compareTo(b);
                            }
                });
```

As you see it makes less code but it is not very readable.

Java 8 addresses this issue.

You could use a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)  :

```
Collections.sort(myList, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

Or a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (lambda expression shorter version) :

```
Collections.sort(myList, Comparable::compareTo);
```

Or the  `Comparator.comparing() static` method  :

```
Collections.sort(myList, Comparator.comparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```